# Can I create an ordinals-like transaction using bcoin / btcwallet?

Tags: bcoin, btcd, ordinals

According to

[Understanding how ordinals work with the Bitcoin blockchain. What is exactly stored on the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/117018/understanding-how-ordinals-work-with-the-bitcoin-blockchain-what-is-exactly-sto)

you can add data to the unexecuted branch of a taproot input like so:

```
OP_0
OP_IF
(embedded data comes here)
OP_ENDIF
```

How would I go about creating such transaction using bcoin or btcwallet?

Answer (score 2):

You can create any kind of script spend with bcoin but for taproot you will need to use the [taproot branch](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/tree/taproot) which has not yet been sufficiently reviewed or released. You can follow along with [this test](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/blob/taproot/test/taproot-check-test.js#L110) to learn how to add a script to a taproot tree, derive the address, send BTC to it and then spend it, revealing the witness